# Can't compare the values in if method

Tags: objective-c

Can't understand that the object is nil:

```
if ([self indexFromObjectProperty:UUID])
    {}
else 
    {}
```

The problem is that indexFromObjectProperty can be 0 but I need to check the situation when there is no such element in array.

```
-(NSInteger)indexFromObjectProperty:(NSString *)property
{
    NSInteger iIndex;
    for (int i = 0; i < [items count]; i++)
    {
        if([property isEqualToString:[[items objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"UUID"]])
        {
            iIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return iIndex;
}
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the `iIndex`, set the value to some default:

```
NSInteger iIndex = NSNotFound;
```

Then you can check it in your `if`:

```
if ([self indexFromObjectProperty:UUID] != NSNotFound)
```

Answer (score 3):

To your Q: You can initialize iIndex with `NSNotFound`. Then you compare to it.

Additionally: `NSPredicate` (and some other suggestions leading too far away from the Q.)